# Killing a Thread gracefully in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, cherrypy

I'm trying to terminate a thread as soon as I press Ctrl + C. I created a class which handles all the operations I want the thread to do periodically. The problem is when KeyboardInterrupt is raised (or SIGINT) the loop stops successfully, but the whole program freezes (I'm using cherrypy as a web server). I've looked around and I can not find a solution for this. Can someone enlighten me?

Code:

main.py

```
from KeywordWorker import main as worker

SMBinWorker = worker.KeywordHandler(SMBinDir, sqlitePath)
SMBinWorker.run()
signal(SIGINT, SMBinWorker.setFlag)
```

My object code:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import join as osjoin
from time import sleep
from signal import signal, SIGINT

from extentions import *

import threading as mp

class KeywordHandler:
def __init__(self, path_to_files, sqlite_path):
    self.shutdown_flag = mp.Event()
    self.pathToFiles = path_to_files
    self.sqlitePath = sqlite_path
    self.queue = list()
    # Files Already Processed
    self.filesProcessed = set()

# start Process
def run(self):
    self.prc = mp.Thread(target=self.worker)
    self.prc.start()

def setFlag(self, foo, bar):
    print "\n  Shutting down Keyword Handler Gracefully.."
    self.shutdown_flag.set()
    self.prc.join()

# determines what to do with file
def extentionResolver(self, fileName):
    # deal with file extention
    pass

# return file count on directory
def getFileCount(self):
    return len([f for f in listdir(self.pathToFiles) if isfile(osjoin(self.pathToFiles, f))])

# return files names
def getFileList(self):
    return [f for f in listdir(self.pathToFiles) if isfile(osjoin(self.pathToFiles, f))]

# reset queue
def reset(self):
    self.queue = list()
    self.filesProcessed = set()

# compares directory to queue
def updateQueue(self):
    # update queue
    pass

# Deal with files in queue    
def resolveQueue(self):
    # resolve queue
    # loop through each file, and at the end of the loop, check shutdown_flag 
    pass


def worker(self):
    while not self.shutdown_flag.is_set():
        if self.getFileCount() > len(self.filesProcessed):
            # Check what's new
            self.updateQueue()
            sleep(0.2)
            # Process queue
            self.resolveQueue()

        sleep(10)
```

Comment: Have you inspected the state of the process after exiting the loop with a debugger? Can you provide a [mcve] without a webserver context? What exactly do you observe?

Comment: You should probably set `server.shutdown_timeout: 0` in config: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull/1528#issuecomment-271227882